# Ajax Get without directory traversal vulnerability

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

According to my understanding of javascript and **directory traversal** someone could **rewrite** the javascript (i.e. GreaseMonkey) and could change the target-file of the Ajax Get request.

In my tests working with **typo3** when using "../" in the ajax get the server responds with the hirachicaly higher page if that page can be accssed by the user. When the user enters a path that is valid he also gets the content of that file.

Is it possible to hide the path used so existing files can't be namely brute-forced and the file does not contain a 'Path Disclosure'?

Or is obfuscation the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no it isn't possible to avoid bruteforcing file names, if the user is allowed to login. For not logged in users you could return a 404 status code if the user isn't logged in, though. Also why use url rewriting when there are browser addons allowing you to send any request.